# PDFBox - copy only the page resources instead of copying all resources of a document

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Using pdfbox, how is it possible to copy only the page resources instead of copying all resources of a document for a single page? This is the code I use to extract the page and add it to a new document but this creates a large file which I think copies all the resources of a document even if I add a single page. Is there any method to compress the contents?

```
pageToAdd = (PDPage) billDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(j-1);
outputDoc.addPage(pageToAdd);
```

Comment: Depending on the PDF creation software, each page in its **Resources** dictionary may reference all document resources instead of only those needed for the page at hand. For such documents you'll see a behavior as you describe.

Comment: Also the "size" of a page is not the size of the document divided by the number of pages. There are shared resources between pages so the size of a single page might be larger than you expect.

Comment: We use FOP to generate the PDF's and there aren't any images that would increase the size drastically - just plain text. The thing is, I have 2 pdf's with the same content but created from different sources. The one I've created with FOP is double the size of the one I've received (not sure where that came from). I have not embedded any fonts either. If FOP is referencing all document resources as mentioned above on a single page, then I would say FOP needs optimization.

Comment: Using PDFBox, is there a way I can split the pages in a PDF copying only the resources that are required for that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy only the required resources when adding or splitting the page. This entirely depends on your needs or what you want to add/remove completely. You can also check mergeInto() to merge COS dictionaries. For example to copy only the fonts:

```
PDResources res = pageToAdd.getResources();
PDResources newres = new PDResources();

newres.setFonts(res.getFonts());
pageToAdd.setResources(newres);
outputDoc.addPage(pageToAdd);
```